# Binding a value of an object to a combobox which is stored in a list

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I want to bind a value of each object stored in a ObersvableCollection to the ComboBox. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserAccounts}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding EMailAddress}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

In the code behind I set the DataContext:

```
this.DataContext = PersitentDataModelUserSettings.Instace.UserAccounts;
```

Here is the Model:

```
public class PersitentDataModelUserSettings : ModelBase
{
    private static PersitentDataModelUserSettings instance = new PersitentDataModelUserSettings();

    public static PersitentDataModelUserSettings Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
        set { instance = value; } 
    }

    private ObservableCollection<AccountSettingsObj> _userAccounts = new ObservableCollection<AccountSettingsObj>();

    public ObservableCollection<AccountSettingsObj> UserAccounts
    {
        get { return _userAccounts; }
        set
        {
            _userAccounts = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UserAccounts");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the object type:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class AccountSettingsObj : ModelBase
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    private string _eMailAddress; 
    public string EMailAddress 
    {
        get { return _eMailAddress; }
        set 
        {
            _eMailAddress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EMailAddress");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: By doesn't work, do you not see any items in the combo box or is the combo box full of blank lines?

Comment: neither nor. the combobox height doesn't change, no matter how many items are in the list.

Comment: What do you mean the height doesn't change? What you've got there shouldn't change the height: it should populate the combobox drop-down list with your UserAccounts. How many items are in your UserAccounts collection by the way?

Comment: Something else to try, remove the ComboBox.ItemTemplate and override the ToString of your AccountSettingsObj to return the email address. This way you can check whether the binding is at fault or not. If you see entries in the drop-down this way then your binding is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting ItemSource of comboBox to this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserAccounts}"
```

but you also setting DataContext of ComboBox to this:

```
this.DataContext = PersitentDataModelUserSettings.Instace.UserAccounts;
```

So binding engine is looking for property `UserAccounts` in `UserAccounts`.

---

This can be fixed in two ways:

- Either set ItemsSource to binding like this:  `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`. This way you are saying `ItemSource` is same as `DataContext` of ComboBox.
- Or set DataContext to instance only : `this.DataContext = PersitentDataModelUserSettings.Instace.UserAccounts;`.
  This way you set *DataContext* to point to instance of *PersitentDataModelUserSettings* and asking BindingEngine to look for property *UserAccounts* in *PersitentDataModelUserSettings*.

Comment: one more question: lets say we have an object in the object and I want to get a value of the inner object. how to reference this. Can I achieve this with point notation?

Comment: `{Binding Path.InnerPath}` - You can use dot in between to refer to inner object. Like we do in code behind, it works same way in XAML as well.